# Regex to exclude optional words and return as list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the name and profession as a list of tuples from the below string using regex.

**Input string**

```
text = "Mr John,Carpenter,Mrs Liza,amazing painter"
```

As you can see the first word is the name followed by the profession which repeats in a comma seperated fashion. The problem is that, I want to get rid of the adjectives that comes along with the profession. For e.g "amazing" in the below example.

**Expected output**

```
 [('Mr John', 'Carpenter'), ('Mrs Liza', 'painter')]
```

I stripped out the adjective from the text using "replace" and used the below code using "regex" to get the output. But I am looking for a single regex function to avoid running the string replace. I figured that this has something to do with look ahead in regex but couldn't make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 text.replace("amazing ", "")
 txt_new = re.findall("([\w\s]+),([\w\s]+)",text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to use word and whitespace characters, this could be another option:

```
(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*,\s*(?:\w+\s+)*(\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `)`  Close group 1
- `\s*,\s*` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars
- `(?:\w+\s+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ word and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmeEc2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Te84Yx)

```
import re
 
regex = r"(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*,\s*(?:\w+\s+)*(\w+)"
s = ("Mr John,Carpenter,Mrs Liza,amazing painter")
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
[('Mr John', 'Carpenter'), ('Mrs Liza', 'painter')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one regex approach using `re.findall`:

```
text = "Mr John,Carpenter,Mrs Liza,amazing painter"
matches = re.findall(r'\s*([^,]+?)\s*,\s*.*?(\S+)\s*(?![^,])', text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('Mr John', 'Carpenter'), ('Mrs Liza', 'painter')]
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\s*        match optional whitespace
([^,]+?)   match the name
\s*        optional whitespace
,          first comma
\s*        optional whitespace
.*?        consume all content up until
(\S+)      the last profession word
\s*        optional whitespace
(?![^,])   assert that what follows is either comma or the end of the input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim Biegeleisen. Now, I am trying t understand this:-)

Comment: @sharathnatraj My feelings exactly.  That's why I tried to add an explanation.

Comment: So this pattern  ".*?" gets rid of the adjective? So you are assuming that adjective will always be followed by space right?

Comment: No, the adjective is assumed to be the last word after the first comma, which is followed by either another comma or the end of the input.